# How To Loop Through Radio Questions Back Button Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to loop through an array of objects with 'back' and 'next' buttons. For some reason it doesn't loop properly. When the 'next' button is pressed, the 'back' button should decrement how every many times more the next button is pressed.

This is the function that is accessing the back button to go back through the sets of radio questions. To see the full code please visit my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzJcy/3/). Thanks!

```
     var questions = {

    allQuestions: [


        {
            topQuestion: [" 1a) Click on which music producer, produced Justins Timberlake 4th Album?", "2a)Click on which famous celebrity did Justin Timberlake date in 1999? ", "3a)Click on which social media movie did Justin Timberlake starred in?", "4a)Click on what famous disney kids show did first Justin Timberlake made his first appearance?", "5a)Click on which famous singer did Justin Timberlake accidently tear clothes off during a performance?", "6a)What magazine named Justin Timberlake the Most Stylish Man In America?"],
            question: "1a)What popular site did Justin Timberlake invest 2.2 Million Dollars in? ",
            choices: ["Linkedin", "Facebook", "Myspace", "Youtube"],

        }, {
            question: "2b)Select which movie did Justin Timberlake film score in 2008?",
            choices: ["The Incredibles", "Shark Tank", "Finding Memo", "Star Wars"],
            correctAnswer: 1
        }, {

            question: "3b)What city was Justin Timberlake born in?",
            choices: ["Chicago", "Detroit", "Tenessee", "New York"],
            correctAnswer: 2
        }, {


]
};

      var newQues = Object.create(questions);

         var k = 0;
         var chngeRadio = 0;


         for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {


    container = document.getElementById("container");
    list = document.getElementById("list");
    var li = document.createElement("input");
    li.type = 'radio';
    li.name = 'radio_group';
    li.id = 'id1';
    li.value = newQues.allQuestions[i].correctAnswer;
    list.style.textAlign = "center";

    document.body.appendChild(li);
    div = document.createElement("div");
    text = document.createTextNode(newQues.allQuestions[0].choices[i]);
    list.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(li);
    div.appendChild(text);

}


     btn1.onclick = function (event) {
        event = EventUtil.getEvent(event);


        k++;

        while (list.firstChild) {
            list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
        };

         for (var m = 0; m < 4; m++) {


            container = document.getElementById("container");
            list = document.getElementById("list");
            var li = document.createElement("input");
            li.type = 'radio';
            li.name = 'radio_group';
            li.id = 'id1';
            li.value = newQues.allQuestions[m].correctAnswer;
            list.style.textAlign = "center";
            div = document.createElement("div");
            text = document.createTextNode(newQues.allQuestions[k].choices[m])
            //alert(k);
            list.appendChild(div);
            div.appendChild(li);
            div.appendChild(text);

        };



          // Assigns a event object to back button, this is where I would like
          // to go back and loop the radio questions but for some reason it only decrements 1 time
    if ( k >= 1) {

        btn2.onclick = function(event){
            event = EventUtil.getEvent(event);

            chngeRadio++;




              function replaceNode() {

             function replaceNode() {

             if (k === 1) {
                 //assigns count to 0
                 chngeRadio -= 1;

             };


             if (k === 2) {
                 //assigns count to 1
                 chngeRadio = 2;
                 chngeRadio -= 1;
             };


         };


         replaceNode()

             while (list.firstChild) {
                list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
            };



            for (var d = 0; d < 4; d++) {


                container = document.getElementById("container");
                list = document.getElementById("list");
                var li2 = document.createElement("input");
                li2.type = 'radio';
                li2.name = 'radio_group';
                li2.id = 'id2';
                li2.value = newQues.allQuestions[d].correctAnswer;
                li2.style.textAlign = "center";
                div2 = document.createElement("div");
                text2 = document.createTextNode(newQues.allQuestions[chngeRadio].choices[d])
                //alert(k);
                list.appendChild(div2);
                div2.appendChild(li2);
                div2.appendChild(text2);

            };

        };

    };


    };
```

Comment: Just so you know, you're missing a comma after the declaration of your questions object, which means that you are accidentally implicitly declaring `newQues`, `k`, `i`, `li`, and `chngeRadio` as global properties.

Comment: thanks @Paul, someone edited my version and made errors on that object

Comment: Yes, @RicoPlasakoi, that was me. Apologies.  I was about to fix my mistake when you re-edited.  The reason for my edit is that your code example is extremely difficult to read because it is so poorly formatted.  I am not going to take the time to edit it again (and risk making another mistake), but for our benefit you might consider tidying up the code.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes your right,  bit of a newbie here..this still a bit new to learning beautiful javascript.. I'm still getting used to formatting my code correctly.. thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd suggest not to use `chngeRadio` and `replaceNode()`function and replace it with `k--`. Also, change the `if` condition over **Back** btn.click to `k>1`.

```
if ( k > 1) {
    btn2.onclick = function (event) {
        event = EventUtil.getEvent(event);
        k--;

        while (list.firstChild) {
            list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
        };

        for (var d = 0; d < 4; d++) {
            container = document.getElementById("container");
            list = document.getElementById("list");
```

...

```
        text2 = document.createTextNode(newQues.allQuestions[k].choices[d]);
        //alert(k);
        list.appendChild(div2);
        div2.appendChild(li2);
        div2.appendChild(text2);
    };
};
```

Comment: Thankszz do much @ Binu and @ Derek..I was thinking about using that k variable to increment though the questions object, I shouldve trusted my guts lol... much appreciated!!